# Помогите разобрать решение задачи

Tags: алгоритм

[Вот сайт с условием и решением](https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/348510/Google-or-OA-2019-or-Maximum-Area-Serving-Cake)

На сайте есть решение как на python3, так и на c++. Объясните пожалуйста почему алгоритм бинарного поиска решает эту задачу. Сразу извиняюсь за возможно глупый вопрос, но я хочу разобраться.

Конкретные вопросы:

1) почему `1 + 1e-5`? что это и почему так важно? Убрав 1e-5 я получил 0 из 13 тестов.

2) `l = x` и `r = x` так же этот момент не понятен.

Условие задачи:

Есть массив, содержащий радиусы круглых тортов и количество гостей, определите самый большой кусок, который можно вырезать из тортов так, чтобы каждый гость получил кусок пирога с одинаковой площадью. Невозможно, чтобы у одного куска была какая-то часть одного торта и какая-то часть другого торта, и каждому гостю подают только один кусок торта.

Решение на Python3

```
def maximumAreaServingCake(radii, numberOfGuests):
areas = [math.pi * r * r for r in radii]
def possible(x):
    k = 0
    for a in areas:
        k += a // x
        if k >= numberOfGuests:
            return True
    return False

l, r = 0, max(areas)
while l + 1e-5 <= r:
    x = (l + r) / 2
    if possible(x):
        l = x
    else:
        r = x
return round(x, 4)
```

Comment: Условие и решение добавь в вопрос, предварительно переведя на русский.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вроде очевидно, что имея некий размер куска, мы можем довольно легко проверить, можем ли мы всем выдать куски данного размера. Также очевидно, что если мы можем выдать куски некого размера, то мы можем вместо них выдать куски любого меньшего размера. Значит имеем монотонную функцию, следовательно можем применить к ней бинпоиск.

> почему 1 + 1e-5?

Там не `1`, а `l`. Это точность вычисления значения.

> Убрав 1e-5 я получил 0 из 13 тестов.

Очевидно, что без них цикл станет вечным даже в том случае, если бы вычисления происходили точно. При неточных, конечно, могли бы быть варианты, но полусумма всё равно не может оказаться больше максимума.

> `l = x` и `r = x` так же этот момент не понятен.

Это обычный алгоритм бинпоиска.

Comment: Я добавил в вопрос конкретные моменты в которых у меня возникает вопрос.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: случайно вместо l написал 1. Так 1e-5 это из-за точности пишется? А можете скинуть ссылку где об этом написано, чтобы впредь не задавать таких вопросов. Просто впервые сталкиваюсь с этим.

Comment: Это просто общепринятые понятие, что точность до 5ого знака после запятой является достаточной. Чем выше точность, тем ближе к бесконечности будет выполнение цикла по времени